# Replace folder name in image src attribute on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While clicking a button/trigger I need to change the folder path name from img/image.jpg to imgdark/image.jpg for all the instances of the specific class ".imageShift". What ever image name that is inserted in the image src should remain the same through out all the occurrences. Just the "img" folder path has to be replaced with "imgdark". I tried a code given below.

```
$('.themeColor').click(function () {
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    var imagePath = $('.imagePath');
    if (getId === 'darkTheme') {

        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
            return attr.replace('img', 'imgdark');
        });
    } else if (getId === 'lightTheme') {
        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
            return attr.replace('imgdark', 'img');
        });
    }
});
```

The above code is working perfectly but on each click I am getting a console error as displayed below. I need to get rid of that console error and also make this work as it does already. Please help with this if anyone have done this already.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (homepage.js:1619)
at z (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.attr (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (homepage.js:1617)
at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLSpanElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Do you have a working jsFiddle example somewhere where you can reproduce the error in the console?

Comment: `if (getId === 'darkTheme')` is there are multiple instances with same id(darkTheme or lightTheme )?

Comment: Just check if the `attr` exists before trying to replace it. There seems to be a case where either the attribute or the `imagePath` class do not exists, so you cannot apply replace on it. I cannot really help you with a solution as i cant see the whole picture, but try using the debugger and step through your function and see why there are cases where the attribute doesn't exists.

Comment: you have to check whether the imagePath having values @Constantin Chirila noted this issues. you need to check whether the imagePath have values otherwise you dont allow to replace the values

Comment: You have a bug. When you change `imgdark` to `img` its actualy changing to `imgdarkdark`. Because replase changing not whole string but part of it **imgdark**dark.
You nedd to use regex in your replace

Comment: @ConstantinChirila Thanks for the reply guys, Please check this fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Kowshikan/umfs90qv/6/
Here I have removed the src attribute as Constantin said. Only in that case I see that console error. Other wise its not sowing up the error. 

But in my real time project I can see the src attributes in all the images ! Its confusing why I am getting that error even when I have both the src attribute and also the class imagePath

Comment: @Smollet777 I faced that issue before but with the above code it works perfectly except for the console error. Please check the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Kowshikan/umfs90qv/6/

Comment: @Kowshikan there is no `src` attribute at all in your html. No wonder its undefined

Comment: @Kowshikan you need to toggle `id` too rite?

Comment: @Smollet777 Oh yeah I removed it purposely to show you the error. In my real time project the same error occurs even when I have the src="image.jpg". That is the issue now.

Comment: @sridharreddy Not the ID just the folders

Comment: @Kowshikan but you are doing `getId` using  `this`. So it will always be the same rite?

Comment: @sridharreddy Yes it will be the same. Only the folders toggle

Comment: @Kowshikan when will it become `lightTheme` then?

Comment: @Kowshikan i've placed `src` to img element(in your fiddle) and error is gone. How does the img element look like on your project exactly?

Comment: @sridharreddy Please check this
jsfiddle.net/Kowshikan/umfs90qv/6

Comment: @Smollet777

<div id="dockIcons">
                    <div class="iconCover iconActive">
                        <img class="dockWorkflow imagePath" title="Workflows & Archives" src="img/workflow.png">
                       </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    $('.themeColor').click(function () {
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    var imagePath = $('.imagePath');
    if (getId === 'darkTheme') {

        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
            if attr {
              return attr.replace('img/', 'imgdark/');
           }
        });
    } else if (getId === 'lightTheme') {
        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
            if attr {
                 return attr.replace('imgdark/', 'img/');
}
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @mdev Thank you so much. This works. I am not even an intermediate and still I cant figure out how that worked. But thanks for your help. It worked with this if block included inside the function. The console error disappeared. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('.themeColor').click(function () {
var getId = $(this).attr('id');
var imagePath = $('.imagePath');
if (getId === 'darkTheme') {

    imagePath.attr('src', 'imgdark/image.jpg');
} else if (getId === 'lightTheme') {
    imagePath.attr('src', 'img/image.jpg');
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have multiple instances of the class .imagePath in multiple images. So this code should work for many images with class .imagePath and not only for a single image image.jpg. This code works only for image.jpg. I actually need to change the img/ alone to imgdark/ in all the images which has class .imagePath.

Comment: what if name of the image is changing? Or there are multiple instances?

Comment: OK! test this solution: $('.themeColor').click(function () {
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    var imagePath = $('.imagePath');
    if (getId === 'darkTheme') {

        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
           if attr {return attr.replace('img/', 'imgdark/');}
        });
    } else if (getId === 'lightTheme') {
        imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
           if attr { return attr.replace('imgdark/', 'img/');}
        });
    }
});

Comment: @mdev Thank you so much. This works. I am not even an intermediate and still I cant figure out how that worked. But thanks for your help. It worked with this if block included inside the function. The console error disappeared. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
$('.themeColor').click(function () {
  $('.themeColor').removeClass('themeActive');
     var getId = $(this).attr('id');
     var imagePath = $('.imagePath');
     if (getId === 'darkTheme') {
      imagePath.attr('src', imagePath.attr('src').replace('img/', 'imgdark/'));
     } else if (getId === 'lightTheme') {
       imagePath.attr('src', imagePath.attr('src').replace('imgdark/', 'img/'));
     }

    $('.imagePath').each(function(index, val) {
     console.log('You changed the image('+(index+1)+') path to:'+$(this).attr('src'))
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="themeColor" id="darkTheme">Dark</button>
<button class="themeColor" id="lightTheme">Light</button>


<img class="imagePath" src="imgdark/sampleimg.jpg" alt="">
<img class="imagePath" src="imgdark/sampleimg.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: This one works but what happens is it replaces the first occurred image in all the instances of the class .imagePath. So all the image tag has same  image. That is the reason why included a function there